# Apple Sign In Testing Flow with Mock Users

Tags: ios, testing, facebook-login, user-experience

Apple have announced if your app includes Facebook/Google Login you must include theirs.

Facebook Login includes "Test Roles" in their developer portal this allows you to create mock users for testing the flow of your app.

Is there anything similar for testing Sign In with Apple flow? Somewhere to create mock users.

It's just I've used my own Apple ID and I'm now out of test apple accounts. Having to create real Apple accounts for one test is unsustainable. How to developers get around this?

[image: M]